# "SQL translate error: Extra placeholder" when using prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, prepared-statement

I'm trying to use prepared statements in my SQL but I can't get it working. I'm getting error **"SQL translate error: Extra placeholder"** when I add something like this to my code

```
if ($cpucooler_socket != "") {

            $myArray = explode(',', trim($cpucooler_socket));

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {

                if(count($myArray)>1) {

                    $socket = $myArray[$i];

                    if ($i === 0) {
                        $query .= " AND (socket LIKE ?";
                        $query_params[] = '%' . $socket . '%';
                    } else if ($i === count($myArray) - 1) {
                        $query .= " OR socket LIKE ?)";
                        $query_params[] = '%' . $socket . '%';
                    } else {
                        $query .= " OR socket LIKE ?";
                        $query_params[] = '%' . $socket . '%';
                    }

                } else {
                    $query .= " AND socket LIKE ?";
                    $query_params[] = '%' . $socket . '%';
                }
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the right syntax that I should be using in this case? If I don't use the for loop and I add only for example this instead:

```
$query .= " AND socket LIKE ?";
$query_params[] = '%' . $myArray[0] . '%';
```

then it's working fine. Here is my full code if it helps:

```
public function getCompatibleMb($case_format_dosky, $cpu_socket, $ram_typ, $pocet_ram, $intel_socket, $amd_socket, $select_after_id, $search) {

    $cpucooler_socket = null;

    if(isset($intel_socket) || isset($amd_socket)){
        if ($intel_socket != null && $amd_socket != null) {
            $cpucooler_socket = $intel_socket.", ".$amd_socket;
        } else if($intel_socket != null) {
            $cpucooler_socket = $intel_socket;
        } else if ($amd_socket != null){
            $cpucooler_socket = $amd_socket;
        }
    } else {
        $cpucooler_socket = null;
    }

    $query_params = array();

    $query = "SELECT id encryptid, id,produkt,vyrobca,dostupnost,cena,socket,series,chipset,form_factor,bluetooth,wifi,rgb,m2,sata3,sietova_karta,zvukova_karta,pci_express_3_0,pci_express_4_0,pci_express_5_0,ram_type,ram_slots,rezim_ram,max_mhz_ram,mosfet_coolers,crossfire_support,sli_support,raid_support,audio_chipset,audio_channels,ext_connectors,int_connectors,max_lan_speed,pci_x16_slots,pci_x4_slots,pci_x1_slots,m2_ports,usb_2_0,usb_3_2_gen_1,usb_3_1_gen_2,usb_3_2_gen_2,sata_3_ports,img_count,produkt_number,vyrobca_url FROM mb_list WHERE dostupnost=1";

    if ($cpu_socket != "") {
        $query .= " AND socket = ?";
        $query_params[] = $cpu_socket;
    } else {
        if ($cpucooler_socket != "") {

            $myArray = explode(',', trim($cpucooler_socket));

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {

                if(count($myArray)>1) {

                    $socket = $myArray[$i];

                    if ($i === 0) {
                        $query .= " AND (socket LIKE ?";
                        $query_params[] = '%' . $socket . '%';
                    } else if ($i === count($myArray) - 1) {
                        $query .= " OR socket LIKE ?)";
                        $query_params[] = '%' . $socket . '%';
                    } else {
                        $query .= " OR socket LIKE ?";
                        $query_params[] = '%' . $socket . '%';
                    }

                } else {
                    $query .= " AND socket LIKE ?";
                    $query_params[] = '%' . $socket . '%';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($ram_typ != "") {
        $query .= " AND ram_type = ?";
        $query_params[] = $ram_typ;
    }

    if ($pocet_ram != "") {
        $query .= " AND ram_slots >= ?";
        $query_params[] = $pocet_ram;
    }

    if($case_format_dosky !="") {

        $myArray = explode(',', trim($case_format_dosky));

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {

            if(count($myArray)>1) {

                $formfactor = trim($myArray[$i]);

                if ($i === 0) {
                    $query .= " AND (form_factor = ?";
                    $query_params[] = $formfactor;
                } else if ($i === count($myArray) - 1) {
                    $query .= " OR form_factor = ?";
                    $query_params[] = $formfactor;
                } else {
                    $query .= " OR form_factor = ?)";
                    $query_params[] = $formfactor;
                }

            } else {
                $query .= " AND form_factor LIKE ?";
                $query_params[] = '%' . $formfactor . '%';
            }
        }
    }

    if ($select_after_id != "") {
        $decrypted = $this->McryptServices->decryptData($select_after_id);
        $query .= " AND id > ?";
        $query_params[] = $decrypted;
    }
    if ($search != "") {
        $new_search = str_replace(" ", "%",$search);
        $query .= " AND produkt LIKE ?";
        $query_params[] = '%'.$new_search.'%';
    }

    $query .= " LIMIT 32";

    $vytah = $this->Database->query($query, $query_params)->fetchAll();

    $arr[] = $vytah;

    foreach ($arr[0] as $key => $value) {
        $arr[0][$key]->{'encryptid'} = $this->McryptServices->encryptData($arr[0][$key]->{'id'});
    }

    return json_encode($arr);

}
```

This is the response after an error:

```
"line":225,"args":[["string","SELECT id encryptid, id,produkt,vyrobca,dostupnost,cena,socket,series,chipset,form_factor,bluetooth,wifi,rgb,m2,sata3,sietova_karta,zvukova_karta,pci_express_3_0,pci_express_4_0,pci_express_5_0,ram_type,ram_slots,rezim_ram,max_mhz_ram,mosfet_coolers,crossfire_support,sli_support,raid_support,audio_chipset,audio_channels,ext_connectors,int_connectors,max_lan_speed,pci_x16_slots,pci_x4_slots,pci_x1_slots,m2_ports,usb_2_0,usb_3_2_gen_1,usb_3_1_gen_2,usb_3_2_gen_2,sata_3_ports,img_count,produkt_number,vyrobca_url FROM mb_list WHERE dostupnost=1 AND (form_factor = ? OR form_factor = ? OR form_factor = ?) LIMIT 32"],["array",[["string","ATX"],["string","mATX (Micro ATX)"],["string","mITX (Mini ITX)"]]]]}
```

Comment: Please add the output of the following to the question: `var_dump($query, $query_params);`

Comment: It didn't work for some reason when I added it to my code. I added the response from the console where you can see the SELECT.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"? Put that code right before you execute the query and put an `exit;` right after. That should give you the output. If the long long string you've added contains the query and the params, please remove everything else, instead of posting a massive string and ask us to search for it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the response to just the query.

Comment: I don't see `socket like ?` anywhere in the query.

Comment: Use `AND form_factor iN (?, ?, ?)` instead of all those `OR`. And you can simplify the way you construct long `AND` and `OR` chains by putting the conditions in an array and then using `implode(' OR ', $conditions)`.

Comment: I don't recognize the output you posted at the end. That's not what `var_dump()` produces.